# Potential bug with iOS html and overflow scrolling

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

I’ve looked around various forums and websites but to no avail, I’ve got a strange bug occurring with my website on iOS (but also in chrome on iOS so I’m not sure if it’s exclusive to iOS devices or just my website is wrong). Essentially, I’ve got a modal called ‘startModal’ which appears to the user when they click a button to start a game, where they can then select which category. The mechanics of the page work as expected but the styling not so much.

Within this `<div>` I have a long list of categories to choose from that exceed the height of the `<div>`, I’ve set the `overflow` property of the `<div>` to scroll (`overflow: scroll;`) and it was working as expected until this morning when scrolling stopped working. However after experimenting I’ve found that simply rotating my iPad from landscape to portrait and back to landscape or vice versa fixes the issue and the `<div>` scrolls, I’m thinking this is an issue with how the page renders but I’m not too sure. I’ve attached the CSS properties below.

**The startModal**

```css
.startModal {
  z-index: 20;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: Black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 30vw;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Each choice element**

```css
.choice {
  left: 5%;
  width: 24vw;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

My startModal follows this template:

```html
<div id="startModal" class="startModal">
  <div class="choice" style="top:10px;background-color:red">Option 1</div>
  <div class=" choice" style="top:20px;background-color:green">Option 2</div>
  <div class=" choice" style="top:30px;background-color:blue">Option 3</div>
</div>
```

I know the styling on the above template doesn’t match the styling of the property but it’s just for show.

I’m not sure what’s causing the issue but I’m more than happy to provide more information. Thanks in advance.
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, I think it was a rendering problem with using the `visibility` property to hide and show my modal. I’ve changed this to `display:none;` and `display:inline-block;` and it’s fixed the issue perfectly.